# Load a page from within an already loaded page

Tags: javascript

It seems like this should be a pretty obvious answer but I'm under pressure for portfolio and I think I may be confusing myself here. I couldn't quite find the answer that I was looking for (which I usually am able to on this site).

Basically I want to load an external page with an image into my gallery. The only catch is that the gallery itself is loaded from an external page.

I was able to successfully implement this when I put the gallery code into its own individually loading window. But when I try it with the original setup, of course, I have to delegate. I know how to set that up, it's just defining the function itself that's giving me problems (where "window" calls the div that contains the gallery on its external page):

```
function showPiece(show) {
window.load(show);
}
```

How do I "delegate" here?

Also, I wanted to make sure I figured out how to click back to the gallery as well. That wasn't working for me either for some reason. Here's what I was using (you can see on the guitar page on the portfolio2.html page):

```
window.on('click',"#back", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
showPage('portfolio.html');
manageNavState($(this));
});
```

Here's my site so you can see in detail what's going on:
[Portfolio Site](http://www.justinfowlerdesign.com/#)

And here's the other gallery page I made:
[Second Gallery Page](http://www.justinfowlerdesign.com/#)

Sorry if this is a dumb question. Thanks in advance everyone!

===EDIT===

Nevermind, my code was perfectly fine. I found out I just had to open and close with html tags in the linked image pages, which I didn't expect because I didn't have to do it elsewhere. One image is still not working, but I'll figure it out.

Comment: are we talking about iFrame?

Comment: Nope, just using javascript to load an external page within a div. You can look at my javascript for more details.